# Adaptive Images+ for WordPress: Integrate with WordPress

Tags: image, wordpress, device, retina

## **Intro**

I decided to create a topic for a script that create adaptive images. I have updated this topic so I can refer. Demand a more focused on a particular answer @ChrisFerdinandi advised me to use the script [Adaptive Images+](http://cferdinandi.github.io/adaptive-images/index.html). This script would do exactly do what I'm looking for.

So I was looking for a script that checked me when the website is visited on a retina screen, like an iPad or iPhone for WordPress.

### **Problem**

I will explain at every step what I did and share my code. Before I share my code and walk-through all steps, I will post some information about my WordPress installation.

I have installed my WordPress installation in a subfolder called `/wordpress`. I am using a custom WP theme, that I have developed on my own. I use featured images for my portfolio items. I create them in my `function.php` file like `add_image_size('thumbnail-portfolio', 300, 200, true);`

According to the installation page of the plugin from Chris Ferdinandi, we start by changing the `.htaccess` file in **step 1**. So, what I did is past everything between the comments `#START Adaptive-Images` and `#END Adaptive-Images` immediately after `RewriteEngine On`.

So my entire file would like this:

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#START Adaptive-Images

#Add any directories you wish to omit from the Adaptive-Images process on a new line.
#Omit plugins, wp-includes and wp-admin content.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content/plugins
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-includes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin

#Send any GIF, JPG, or PNG request that IS NOT stored inside one of the above directories
#to adaptive-images.php so we can select appropriately sized versions
RewriteRule .(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php

#END Adaptive-Images

RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

#END WordPress
```

Ok, after modifying the `.htaccess` file, I uploaded to the server. I update it inside the `/wordpress` subfolder. Fine that's done, let's go to **step 2.** This step I have skipped because this was an optional option.

Right **step 3.** I uploaded `adaptive-images.php` into the same directory as my `.htaccess` file, for clarity I have both files uploaded in the subdir. `/wordpress`.

**Step 4.** I add the cookie script right after the beginning `<head>` before all other scripts will run. My entire file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title('|'); ?></title>

<!-- Meta Tags -->
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/960.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/isotope.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script>
    document.cookie='resolution='+Math.max(screen.width,screen.height)+("devicePixelRatio" in window ? ","+devicePixelRatio : ",1")+'; path=/';
</script>

<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>

<?php
    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
?>

</head>
```

Alright that's also done. In **step 5.** I have add the snippet of code to my css file.

Okay, the last step. **Step 6** is testing all the stuff, here is probably the problem immediately clear. Since I have access to a mobile device retina, I decided first to look my site on that device. Unfortunately, only small resolution pictures shown, so that the image is not clear focus. I then looked as **step 6** indicates that if there are really new images are created and stored/saved. There is an `ai-cache` folder created by the script `adaptive-images.php`, but this is unfortunately empty.

Something to notice, is that I have set the featured image size to the normal size and not to the retina version. So `300x200` is for default view, for retina would be the size `600x400px`

### **What have I done?**

I have checked the debug page of the script. I noticed that the cookie will be set as `resolution`. When I replace the line `RewriteRule .(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php` in `.htaccess` to `RewriteRule .(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ test.png` all images will be override by that one.

Error will be given after remove the comment before the error call. Every path is linking right.

I tried to change the permissions of the folder `ai-cache` from `755` to `777` with no results.

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success with Adaptive Images, but it involves a bit of manual work. http://cferdinandi.github.io/adaptive-images/

Comment: Thank you Chris for your comment. So this could work with WordPress?

Comment: Definitely. I'm using it myself for a photographer website on WP.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind though - the biggest the image can ever be is the size of the original, so that should be big enough for retina displays. You should also aim for about 70 quality/value for jpgs to keep size and load times down.

Comment: Glad to hear that it is compatible with WordPress. I've been a long time looking for a proper solution, have tried various plugins including WP 2x Retina, but it doens't work for all sizes. I also busy with creating a photography / graphic design website, so I find it very important that everything works fine. 
So when this works with WordPress, I just only need to upload the retina version of the image?
May I ask you, if you can show me the code, how you did the code integrate with WordPress? There I would be very happy with it.. :)

Comment: @Caspert - You can find detailed installation instructions here: http://cferdinandi.github.io/adaptive-images/installation.html. Click on the expanded options to see some WP specific details. And yes, just upload your 2x images and Adaptive Images will take care of the rest - scaling down as required.

Comment: I should mention: This is not a plugin. It does require you to manually add it to your site, and make a few slight modifications to your `.hataccess` file.

Comment: That's ok haha, I will give it a try. Should I modify the htaccess of WordPress or from my own site?

Comment: I have tried a lot to get it work, but with no success. I followed the tutorial on your website, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work for me. Some details: I have installed WordPress in a sub-directory like `/wordpress`. When I check the source code, I can't find a `.htaccess` file. I change the permalinks to a more user-friendly one, than the `.htaccess` will be visible. Paste your code in the right place, upload the file `adaptive-images.php` in the root of the sub-dir `/wordpress` and copy/past the cookie script in `header.php` before the closing head tag `</head>`. >

Comment: > I use featured images for my portfolio items. I create them in my `function.php` file like `add_image_size('thumbnail-portfolio', 600, 400, true);` - I don't know if I should set the size of the thumbnails to the retina version as my example above or to the normal size that should be 300x200px. Hope you can help me get it work!

Comment: I have do all the debugging for now. Test image will be override all images. Error will given after set this snippet in the file `adaptive-images.php`. Every path is linking right. Doesn't know what I am doing wrong. See my previous comments for more details about my WP installation. For better understand, this script will also works when I upload the files with the media uploader of WordPress? Right? @ChrisFerdinandi

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you yet. I'll respond with more detail tomorrow.

Comment: Alright so... for what you're trying to do: 1. Modify the WordPress `.htaccess`, and add the Adaptive Images stuff just after `RewriteEngine On`, above the WP specific stuff. If you can't see the file, it may be a server or FTP setting. WP always generates an `.htaccess` file even without pretty permalinks.

Comment: It sounds like based on your debugging, the `.htaccess` file is working. That's good. Also sounds like all directories are pointing the right place. That's also good. There's a good chance, given the image sizes you're working with, that the existing images are just the right size, so AI isn't resizing anything. You might try using a REALLY small cookie value (say 100) just to force a cache.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean that an AI Cache folder isn't being generated, or the images you're being served aren't any different in size, or...?

Comment: First of, thanks for helping. You said that WordPress generates automatically a `.htaccess` file, but that doesn't do it for me. Only when I change the permalinks to user-friendly one the file exists. Ok that I have done for now. I have do for a third time debug the source, everything works I think. Some facts. So my WordPress theme is installed in a subfolder like `/wordpress`. I have set the file `adaptive-images.php` into the same directory as the `.htaccess` of WordPress in `/wordpress`subfolder. >>

Comment: >> The cookie `resolution` will exists, the second method of `test.jpg` works, all images are replaced by `test.jpg`. The third method will show the error with the following results: http://d.pr/i/h35n Notice that I have placed WordPress in a subdir `/wordpress` I don't know if the `document_root` is right than, because there is no `/wordpress` after the path.

Comment: >> Also I have noticed yet that when I turn the permalinks to default, because my portfolio template will not work when I change it to user-friendly one, that the everything between the comments of Adaptive images will not exists. Only the following is shown: http://snippi.com/s/yoberfz

Comment: My answer on your last question:
The folder `ai-cache` will be generated, now inside the subfolder `wordpress` but sometimes the was generated in the root. The folder is empty. Regard to the image size are everywhere the same size, the normal image shown on a non retina display is correct, but it will also be displayed on a retina display and not the retina version 2x as large, so on a retina display the images are not sharp.

Comment: I don't know if the following snippet is correct to use retina images in WordPress: `add_image_size('thumbnail-portfolio', 300, 200, true);` In the example above I use the normal size for the thumbnails, so the retina version has a size of 600x400px 2x as large. Is this right or should I set the thumbnail size to retina size and not to normal non retina size?

Alot of information, but I hope you have now all the information you need to help me out, to get this beautiful script working in my own theme! Thank you all very much!

Comment: One more test that I have done. When I let the file `adaptive-images.php` by default, the `ai-cache` folder is created in the root of my site, when I change the rule from `$document_root  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` to `$document_root  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress';` the folder is generated in the subfolder of `/wordpress`. Only by the last one, all uploaded images with the media uploader of WordPress gives a error like this: http://d.pr/i/dX9W

Comment: I have tried a lot, but with no result. Hope you can help me out!
In your small tutorial for debugging you point to a few possible reasons why the script isn't working.

Ok, I will give you the results. **Step 1:** Yes, the cookie will be set, called `resolution`. **Step 2:** All images will be replaced by the the `test.jpg` image. And the last step it will receive a image with the error.. You noticed that often a problem with WordPress installations for the last step. I think that there is the error... There will only create a `ai-cache` outside the wordpress subfolder where WP is installed.

Comment: Please check my updated Question. Hopefully you have something to the information given and you can help me further, so that we get the script to work.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was moving this weekend. That actually really narrows it down. Rather than forcing the cache folder to appear in the WordPress subfolder, just adjust the right variable to reflect to the path. I had to do the same thing on my setup.

Comment: So what can I do the best? And for clarity, this script also works for images that are uploaded to the media library of WordPress, right? And should I set the size of the thumbnails in `functions.php` to the retina version or to the normal size? Now I have set it to the normal size: `add_image_size('thumbnail-portfolio', 300, 200, true);`

Comment: Hi Caspert - I'm not sure I understand your first question ("What can I do the best?"). As for image quality, you might want to go retina and let the application downscale them as needed. BUT, you need to make sure your container width is set to the size of the thumbnail container, or it won't touch those images at all. And yes, ANY image file gets routed through Adaptive Images first.

Comment: I mean with my first question ("What can I do the best?") with that it won't work for me. You noticed me to check "just adjust the right variable to reflect to the path". How can I do that?

Comment: You said the debugging error image gives you the path of the the image folder? I would just make sure that's where the variables in the file point to. This tool definitely requires a working knowledge of PHP, so it may be not be the best solution for you.

Comment: Yes the error will give me the path to my image folder of my custom theme, I don't know if there should the path to the `uploads` folder of WordPress were WP saves the images that were uploaded with the media uploader instead of my image folder of the theme. Error that was given: http://d.pr/i/h35n

Comment: There doesn't need to be a case folder in your uploads folder. The way adaptive images works is by routing any request for an image on your site, regardless of the source folder, through adaptive-images.php. This is a new copy of the image, scaled to the appropriate size, to the specified case folder. If you comment out the debug code, what exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: All is working, also the ai-cache map will be generated by adaptive-images.php. Only when I upload images with the media uploader, there will be now new images be generated in ai-cache. Also when I have check the website on a retina device..

Comment: Glad things are working. Yes, new images should be generated in the ai-cache folder. If your problem has been solved, could you mark this answer as correct?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, but my problem is for now not solved. So the map will be generated, but not with new images... I don't know what I should do now?

Comment: Sounds like the images you're uploading are big enough. You might try adjusting the image wrap variable to fit your image size better.

Comment: The images that I uploaded are 600x400px and the container where the image are stored is 300x200px... So I think that's right?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the easiest solution is to make one image -- twice the norm -- compress it, and call it on non retina displays at half its size.

See explanation here...

```
 http://silev.org/test/Retina-resize.html
```